# How does Mercurial treat equivalent changesets?

Tags: mercurial

My setup is as follows: I've a repository R with default branch and another named branch "a". On both branches, there exists a file "myFile.txt". I've cloned repository R, yielding the clones R_1 and R_2. Now I "hg up default" in R_1 and "hg up a" in R_2. In both working directories of R_1 and R_2, I "echo 'a' >> myFile.txt". Subsequently, I "hg ci -m 'fix in default' and "hg ci -m 'fix in a' in R_1 and R_2, respectively. Next, I "hg push" in both directories.

In R, I can now "hg up default" and "hg up a" and see the fix in both branches (which is expected). However, hg log appears to only reflect one changeset with one commit message. My feeling is that somehow Mercurial figures out that the changesets are equivalent and "merges" them, which is probably the right thing to do for efficiency.

Is this correct? How does it work? Which commit-message is actually chosen? This may sound like an artificial setup but I'm actually encountering this situation in a real setup (obviously more complicated) and want to make sure that nothing bad happens.

Comment: Your question is unreadable. Please [format it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28540557/edit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a part of `hg help log`:

```
  Note:
   for performance reasons, log FILE may omit duplicate changes made on
   branches and will not show removals or mode changes. To see all such
   changes, use the --removed switch.
```

So you should be able to see both changesets this way.

I'm not sure which change will be shown and which will not. This will probably depend on how the history is built up in your repository. Since this is not mentioned, you probably can't rely on that.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware that this was just a feature of the log command.